# Notice and termination

Tags: notice-period

Ive recieved a text on sunday from my boss saying:

Hi Stacey, myself & the md have had a meeting & decided it is best for all concerned if you didn't come in to work for the foreseeable future.
You will be contacted by hr as soon as me & md have met with her.

I then recieved a letter  today thay says ive been given a months notice that ends on the 30th June letter is dated 3rd july ... theres no reason stated for my termination of contract im at a loss and would appreciate any advice. What can i do about mynotice period and the lack of details ive been given?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume this is USA based, if so, what STATE?

Comment: It would be useful if you could provide a little bit more of info (e.g. which country?)

Comment: On another note, I would not spend too much time dwelling on this, you were given a generous 2 months severance.  Start applying for new jobs while your still getting paid, and when asked what happened, tell the truth -- you were laid off.

Comment: Very unfortunately, a company does not really have to give a reason for firing you.  Regarding 30th of JUNE, that sounds strange?  is that a typo?

Comment: @Fattie In some states in the USA, the company can let you go for no reason at all AND is not obligated to provide any severance ( although most do ).

Comment: I would query the date discrepancy, just something like "Could you please confirm the end of my notice period? Your letter says 30th June". Other than that, you can *ask* for an explanation but they don't have to give you one.

Comment: hi Mr. P. - right, that's just what I said.  regarding 30th JUNE, it sounds like a typo here or elsewhere.  ie, it says "a month's notice", something doesn't add up.

Comment: VTC as too vague.

Comment: Who is Julie? Your HR person? I'm assuming when you hear from her you will get a lot of the details you are missing.

Comment: You use the words "termination of contract", but just to confirm - you do actually have a real "contract"? That being a written agreement, signed by both you and your boss, describing all of the terms of your employment (including things like notice period, etc).

Comment: @MisterPositive or to call it more specifically, the employment at will doctrine

Comment: so cowardly to fire you on sunday via text message.

Comment: Hi thank u for your responses I am in the UK. I do have a full contract signed by myself and my employer. I have just spoken to  my HR manager, Julie who confirmed my notice is until the end of July. She did however say two things i take issue with. Firstly that i didnt fit into the idea of the md's (Diana) 'ladies' and more specifically that Diana  had taken issue with me wearing jeans on the machine  shop floor where the other male employees wear jeans and the second issue that ive been let go for having last week off which was a booked holiday. its booked  and agreed so how can i b fired?

Comment: Its not a company i want to stay with after being  treated so poorly believteme. Im sure there are better employers out there. I just think i should be treated fairly

Comment: @StaceyKenny if you expect to be treated fairly by employers then you are setting yourself up for a lifetime of disappointment.

Answer (score 3):

Please check that letter again. If the letter actually says you are given notice to the 30th of June, not the 30th of July, then most likely you haven't been given notice, because you can't be given notice for a date in the past. That would be a stupid mistake by your employer. You should call them about this. And I believe they cannot just say "sorry, we meant 30th of July", they would have to give you notice again. Say 1 month from 6th of July if they are quick.

Apart from that: Not much you can do. You will be paid to the end of your notice period without having to work, and probably should use that time to find a new position.